# XSL and Schematron errors when XMLSpy upgraded to 2019

Tags: xml, xslt, xmlspy

Until XMLSpy upgraded to 2019, the scripts we used were working just fine. The individual that created them does not work here anymore. Now we are receiving error messages when using the script for transformation and when validating it. Does anyone understand how to correct the problem?

thanks,

Rachel

Error message when using the script:

```
File S:\Metadata\Code\Schematron\Schematron_ETD.xsl: XSL transformation failed
                Cannot retrieve resource 'S://Metadata/ETD/Staging/MODS/u0015_0000001_0003253.mods.xml'
                              Error location: xsl:stylesheet / xsl:template / xsl:for-each / xsl:apply-templates / @select
                                Details
                                                System Error 2: The system cannot find the file specified.
                                                I/O Error 400: Don't know how to deal with relative URI (scheme name is missing).
                                                I/O operation on file 'S:\\Metadata\ETD\Staging\MODS\u0015_0000001_0003253.mods.xml' failed.
                                                FODC0002: Cannot use the URI supplied as the first argument to the 'doc' function, to retrieve a resource containing XML
```

Part of the error message when validating:

```
File S:\Metadata\ETD\Documentation\xmllists\20190605xmlList.xml is not valid.
    File S:\Metadata\Code\Schematron\Schematron_ETD.xsl has errors.
        Neither an element declaration nor a type definition is known for element . Strict assessment failed.
            Error location: xsl:stylesheet
            Details
                cvc-assess-elt.1: Neither an element declaration nor a type definition is known for element . Strict assessment failed.
        Neither an element declaration nor a type definition is known for element . Strict assessment failed.
            Error location: xsl:stylesheet / xsl:import
            Details
                cvc-assess-elt.1: Neither an element declaration nor a type definition is known for element . Strict assessment failed.
```

Comment: What happens if you replace `S://Metadata/ETD/Staging/MODS/u0015_0000001_0003253.mods.xml` whereever it is used with `file:///S:/Metadata/ETD/Staging/MODS/u0015_0000001_0003253.mods.xml`.

Comment: The transformation script does not actually look like that it looks like: <xsl:value-of select="concat('S:\Metadata\ETD\Staging\MODS', normalize-space(Assigned_Filename), '.mods.xml')"/> The file name in the error message is coming from the file names in the directory.

Comment: For the first error I still think that using proper file URI syntax with e.g. `file:///S:/Metadata/ETD...` and forwards slashed in the rest instead of the Windows file path like `S:\Metadata\ETD...` might fix that. But with XMLSpy and Altova it seems easier to use their support anyway then hoping to find expertise on StackOverflow.